# How to upgrade zookeeper from 3.4.5 to 3.4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, zookeeper

I am having trouble with a zookeeper ensamble where one node is not able to join the quorum. [Zookeeper will not join the cluster. How to apply patch/upgrade?](https://serverfault.com/questions/749443/zookeeper-will-not-join-the-cluster-after-removing-database-post-corruption/749479#749479) This seems to be related to a bug which has been fixed in 3.4.6

Now the question is, how to upgrade within Ubuntu 14.04.3? I have already done `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but the version still is `Zookeeper version: 3.4.5--1, built on 06/10/2013 17:26 GMT`

This is a production environment and it is important that the service stays live. Right now it is operational with 2 zookeeper nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The zookeeper service is a java process executing `/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar`, which is a symlink to `/usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar`. I have downloaded the new version of zookeeper, stopped the service, copied the new jar to `/usr/share/java/` and pointed the symlink to the new jar, then started the service:

```
sudo cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar /usr/share/java/
sudo rm /usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar /usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar
```

Comment: I have followed your answer. But seeing some problem while upgrading to zookeeper 3.4.13. I have posted the details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090357/how-to-upgrade-zookeeper-from-from-3-8-to-3-13